# Calculate difference between two Times

Tags: apex

Given two Time variables (not DateTimes), how can I calculate the difference (in minutes, seconds, or milliseconds, doesn't matter) between the two?

```
Time startTime = user.Appointment_Start_Time__c;
Time endTime = user.Appointment_End_Time__c;
Long timeAvailable = (endTime.minute() - startTime.minute());
System.debug(timeAvailable);
```

This returns a `-9` with the following variables:

```
startTime | 35100000
endTime | 48600000
```

and these user assignments:

[image]

If I use `millisecond()` it returns a `0`. What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hour(), minute(), second(), and millisecond() methods return the value as you'd expect if you were telling someone what time it is. For example, if I say it is ten minutes past six (assume early morning), hour returns 6, minute returns 10, etc. `hour` returns a value from 0 to 23, `minute` from 0 to 59, `second` from 0 to 59, and `millisecond` from 0 to 999.

To get a difference in time, subtract the milliseconds via getTime:

```
Long timeAvailable = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
```

The getTime method returns the number of milliseconds since Jan 1st, 1970, midnight GMT. This math gives you a difference in milliseconds. From there, to get the minutes, divide by 60,000:

```
timeAvailable /= 60000;
```

Note that even though milliseconds are an attribute of datetime, the database does not currently store or return milliseconds, so millisecond() called on a value from the database will always be zero.

---

Full Example:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.newInstance(Date.today(), user.Appointment_Start_Time__c);
DateTime endTime = datetime.newinstance(Date.today(), user.Appointment_End_Time__c);
Long timeAvailable = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
timeAvailable /= 60000;
System.debug(timeAvailable);
```

---

Without converting to DateTime values, you need to calculate the hours and minutes, and subtract the difference;

```
Time startTime = user.Appointment_Start_Time__c;
Time endTime = user.Appointment_End_Time__c;
Long timeAvailable = (endTime.hour() * 60 + endTime.minute()) -
                     (startTime.hour() * 60 + startTime.minute());
```

Comment: This gives an `Unexpected token 'timeAvailable'.` for the `Long` assignment.

Comment: @CD-RUM Wait, you're using time fields, aren't you? I just realized that. One more sec.

Comment: @CD-RUM See edit; we convert the time to datetimes, then subtract the difference between those. It's not the only way to do this, but probably the easiest.

Comment: Ah, thank-you so much! It constantly surprises me how often you're able to help me.

Comment: would the number of minutes go beyond `interger` so `long` is needed?

Comment: @XiXiao I just copy-pasted-modified code. Integer is indeed much longer than a 24-hour window in milliseconds, so Integer would actually be more appropriate in real code.